# I'm confused about the assosiation in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have learned that in Sequelize, we can add foreign keys to child model by two ways. One is to use `hasOne`,`belongsTo`,`hasMany` and so on. Another way is to add `references` to the props when we config the model like this:

```
trainer_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: "trainers",
      key: "id"
    }
  }
```

so What's the difference of them? I found it's simplier using refrences. I would appreciate it if you can give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing - adding the `references` key - will just mean that there is a foreign key set up at the database level. Using `hasOne`, `belongsTo`, `hasMany`, etc, will do what you're doing above, but in addition, it will also add relevant convenience methods to your model instances to fetch associated records.

Eg. if you use BlogPost `belongsTo` Category, then you'll be able to call `blogPost.getCategory()` and sequelize will handle it for you. It automatically added the `getCategory` method to your blogPost instance because you defined the `belongsTo` relationship. As far as I know, those extra convenience methods are NOT included if you don't declare the `hasOne`/`belongsTo`/`hasMany` associations, and just use `references`.

Comment: Thanks. It's more clear now. Maybe I should have more try in my hand.